# Use of Thread in java in reading and writing a file

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make a program that reads a file line by line and then writes those lines to another file. I want to solve this problem using two separate Threads. The first Thread reads a line and then passes it to the other Thread, which is responsible for writing that line to another file, via message. This process should be repeated until end of file is reached.

How can I do this?

Comment: and, what have you tried ?

Comment: Looks like an assignement you do not really want to do :D

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.  SO is not a place where you can expect people to do all your work for you.

Comment: I think this was a useful question. Yes, it could have been worded better, but Tudor did an excellent job interpreting what was really being asked and provided a general answer with good information, but not doing all the work for the inquirer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [producer-consumer model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). That's not very hard to implement using two `Thread` objects and an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). Here's some start-up code:

```
// we'll store lines of text here, a maximum of 100 at a time
ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(100);

// code of thread 1 (producer)
public void run() {
   while(/* lines still exist in input file */) {
       String line = // read a line of text
       queue.put(line); // will block if 100 lines are already inserted
   }
   // insert a termination token in the queue
}

// code of thread 2 (consumer)
public void run() {
   while(true) {
       String line = queue.take(); // waits if there are no items in the queue
       if(/* line is termination token */) break;
       // write line to file
   }   
}
```

Hope this helps. I cannot give the full code, it's better if you try to fill the gaps yourself.

Comment: Is there any other alternative other than ArrayBlockingQueue, because i don't know the capacity of queue in advance.

Comment: 100 is not the capacity, it's just how many lines you transfer at a time between producer and consumer. It can be any value that you chose and does not depend on the total number of lines in the file.